# bootstrap modal automatically hide in jquery.Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have a function below and my modal is hide when success that i do not want:

```
function saveInventoryData(eventButton) {
    $.ajax({
        url : url,
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        data: jSONInventory,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: MediaType.APPLICATION_JON,
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            closeWaitingDialog();
            if (data.status == false) {
                ERROR_WHEN_UPDATE = true;
            } else if (data.status == true) {
                ERROR_WHEN_UPDATE = false;
            }
            result = data.data;
            CHANGED_EVENT = false;
            $('#message-common').modal('show');
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //closeWaitingDialog();
            LOG(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    }); 
}
```

Please guide me the correct way to achieve my objective .

Comment: use like success: function(data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not given the html code for the modal and and not mentioned bootstrap version.By default bootstrap's modal's buttons have the data-dismiss="modal" attribute.This attribute tells that the modal should be closed when you click on that.Please check out this.Remove this if have written the click event for this button.Else please post your html code for modal to help you.